# Import only the "get" function from lodash into typescript

Tags: typescript, lodash

How can I import only the `get` funtion from `lodash`.

I manged to import the complete `lodash` library by installing it and it's type. However I only need the `get` function. Is there a way?

My code (in angular but unrelated)

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import _ from "lodash";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-lodash-get',
  templateUrl: './lodash-get.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./lodash-get.component.scss']
})
export class LodashGetComponent implements OnInit {

  readonly test = {
    level1: {
      level2: {
        level3: 'level3',
        array: [
          {
            data: "test"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  };

  r1 = false;
  r2= false;
  _ : any = null;

  constructor() {
    this._ = _; 
   }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.r1 = _.get(this.test, 'level1.level2.level3', "No found");
    this.r2 = _.get(this.test, 'level1.level2.foo', "No found");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[mdn import](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import) states that you can import some functions from a module with brackets : 
 `import {get} from 'lodash';`

Comment: Cool, maybe you wanna add a example to you answer ;)

Answer (score 2):

The currently recommended way to ensure the minimum packet size is: `import get from 'lodash/get'`